# Print time output on one line instead of scrolling, python 2

Tags: python, time, terminal

Is there a way of printing the time output on one line instead of scrolling down the page.

```
while True:
    import datetime
    import pytz
    T = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in python 2, do below, i try on my python2.7, its also working even without the `sys.stdout.flush()`

```
while True:
    import datetime
    T = datetime.datetime.now()
    print "{}\r".format(T), ;sys.stdout.flush()
```

in python 3

```
while True:
    import datetime
    T = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(T, end='\r', flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import sys
import os


os.system('setterm -cursor off')
while True:
    T = datetime.datetime.now()
    sys.stdout.write(str(T))
    sys.stdout.write('\b' * 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can import print from python 3 and do:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import sys
import datetime

while True:
    T = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(T, end="\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.4)
```

This solution is based on the [following gist](https://gist.github.com/alfasin/8c4cf0733164d28a4b7c)